# How can I get a cedilla within an equation block?

Tags: latex

I'm writing a document in latex and I can't get the cedilla character working within an equation block. My current charset is utf8, \c{c} don't work as stated in many LaTeX documents.

I'm trying the following:

```
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:accuracy}
    confiança = \frac{tp + tn}{tp + fp + fn + tn} 
\end{equation}
```

The workaround given [here](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=5791) don't work.

Comment: Do you really need the cedilla? For variable names it's expected and reasonable that certain language features fall by the wayside. For example, in English we use the apostrophe to form the genitive case, but almost no variable syntax allows for apostrophes, so they get abandoned when writing software.

Comment: The document is actually a thesis being written in Portuguese. I have to translate whenever possible and it's not like i like it :) some terms became really weird when translated, so in some cases I have to stick with the English word. This is not the case.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! (La)TeX-related questions are better asked at http://tex.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues here. First, `\c{c}` does not work in math mode. You need to switch back to text mode (`\textit` preserves the italics and does not require `amsmath`):

```
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:accuracy}
    confian\textit{\c{c}}a = \frac{tp + tn}{tp + fp + fn + tn} 
\end{equation}
```

The second is that writing a full word in math mode will give you terrible kerning. Compare with this:

```
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:accuracy}
    \textit{confian\c{c}a} = \frac{tp + tn}{tp + fp + fn + tn} 
\end{equation}
```